# How to make long Windows paths work with cl.exe

Tags: c++, windows, cl

Refined the causing issue, it seems to be a result of CL.exe not working with long path names. Calling **cl.exe** directly on a C file in a path with a long folder name results in a "file not found" error

Things I have tried:

1. I have turned on long paths in both the registry and the group policy as per the instructions on the Microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd).
2. I have restarted my computer multiple times and confirmed that the settings are still set after restart but this has not resolved my issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the sample project where this issue can be seen:

> C:\ReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFolderName\SomeReallyReallyReallyLongSubfolderName\main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Running **dir** to confirm file exists:

```
C:\ReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFolderName\SomeReallyReallyReallyLongSubfolderName>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9A59-A85C

 Directory of C:\ReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFolderName\SomeReallyReallyReallyLongSubfolderName

07/09/2021  04:12 PM    <DIR>          .
07/09/2021  04:12 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/02/2021  02:22 PM                95 main.cpp
               1 File(s)             95 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  211,606,155,264 bytes free
```

Running **cl.exe main.cpp**:

```
C:\ReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFolderName\SomeReallyReallyReallyLongSubfolderName>cl main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29914 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'main.cpp': No such file or directory

C:\ReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFolderName\SomeReallyReallyReallyLongSubfolderName>cl \\?\C:\ReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFolderName\SomeReallyReallyReallyLongSubfolderName\main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29914 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '\\main.cpp': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is likely not a CMake issue but a Windows issue. Long file path support has to be enabled. There is a Registry value you can set to enable long path names: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled`

Comment: As I mentioned in my list of things I already tried. This AND the group policy options are both turned on.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: No problem. I expected that to work as well. I'm pulling my hair out over this 

Comment: Conan normally puts it's packages in c:\.Conan to avoid this problem https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#short-paths-reference. cmake does support long paths https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19675 the issue likely lies with your compiler

Comment: @AlanBirtles Looks like you were correct, its a problem with cl.exe. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @jkb after enabling that the app still needs to opt-in to use long paths with the manifest file. The most correct solution is to add a [\\?\ suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#namespaces)

Comment: One year has passed, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Sadly no @GabrielDevillers I ended up just storing my conan packages in C:\.conan